# Using sed to replace line results in two lines for each one replaced

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, unix

I have been trying to automate something, using sed in a loop I wanted to do this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  sed -r -i '' "\"s|::set-output name=(.*)::(.*)\"|\"\1=\2\" >> \$GITHUB_OUTPUT|p" "$line"
done < <(grep -RIl "::set-output" | sort -u)
```

This should feed a list of files returned by grep which match the pattern to sed, which should replace each line with a similar line that matches the new format I want.

This seems to work fine, but it has some unintended results that I cannot explain, every time it replaces one line, it results in two new lines. I don't know what behaviour is causing this and my initial searches around the subject haven't resulted in much useful information and I am not sure what to look in to.

To reproduce the issue, I `set -x`, ran my loop and grabbed one of the lines from the debug output. I reset my repo back to default with `git stash` and then did:

```
$ sed -r -i '' 's|"::set-output name=(.*)::(.*)"|"\1=\2" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT|p' ./.github/workflows/platform-status.yml
```

Now I can see in the `git diff` that it has replaced my old line with two identical lines:

```
-          echo "::set-output name=version::${VERSION}"
+          echo "version=${VERSION}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
+          echo "version=${VERSION}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

I don't understand where the second line is coming from and I wouldn't expect this behaviour from sed, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As this might be hard to reproduce by others, can you create a sample input file (basically by running the grep part) and add this to the question?

Comment: Try with the `-n` flag.  I mostly stopped using `sed` in favor of `awk` but if memory serves, `sed` will by default print the results *in addition* to explicit print commands.  The `-n` flag will suppress printing except for explicit print commands.

Comment: Thanks @Allan, I originally used `sed -rn -i` but when I tried that it removed everything in the file and replaced it with just the lines it should have written in the file. maybe I should try to fix that instead...

Comment: That behavior doesn’t sound right.  `sed` should only be replacing text it matches.  If it’s matching everything and only writing when the pattern is matched, there’s something major missing there.  The `-i` flag will write the changes in place.  Try writing to a new file to see if it works as expected (just for diagnosis)

Comment: Here’s a `sed` command I used (on FreeBSD, but should work on macOS) to remove the comment (`#`) from the `wheel` line in `sudoers`.  This parses the whole file and only changes the relevant line:  `sed -n -i .backup '/^# %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL/ s/^#//' ${FILE}`. The `.backup` makes a backup file automatically with that extension.

Comment: I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54932255/1357569 which suggested changing `sed -r -i ''` with `perl -pi -e` and it works perfectly (after adding an extra escape on the escaped $)

Answer (score 1):

I found a post on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54932255/1357569), which suggested using perl instead:

```
sed -r -i ''
```

becomes

```
perl -pi -e
```

And it works exactly as I would expect

Comment: A decent workaround and easy to test for others. +1 even if Apple stops shipping `perl` it should be widely available and installable if it should get dropped in an update to the OS.